# Discrepancy in stock volume amounts at Yahoo, Google, Stock Market Watch and the official website of a company

Tags: equities, volume, yahoofinance

I have a question regarding differing stock volume amounts for a specific stock reported on various financial websites.
For example, let's take a look at Lockheed Martin's volume amount at **12-12-2016**.

Yahoo Finance:  **7 080 300**
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/LMT/history?period1=1481238000&period2=1481583600&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d

Google Finance:  **7 080 271**
https://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=21553&startdate=Dec+9%2C+2016&enddate=Dec+13%2C+2016&num=30&ei=wrWEWIGdIMWCswHOr4No

Stock Market Watch: **7 079 560**
*"You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links."*

and finally the Lockheed Martin's official website: **7 078 760**
*"You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links."*

My guess is that it perhaps could be a result of some data providers including pre-market and after-hours trading into the calculation of the volume but still, 4 different numbers?

I hope someone can explain this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Despite a lot of effort put into finding the answer to my question, I still have not been able to satisfactorily answer it.